# How to support user added columns?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have this database first EF6 model based on the standard structure of a `ERP SQL Server` database, however, customers are allowed to add user columns to some tables, defining the column name and data type.

Example: a customer may add a u_color nvarchar column to his Products table, another customer on his implementation may add a `u_1stPurchaseDate`  `DateTime` to his Products table.

So this Products table share a standard set of columns across all customers where the ERP is implemented, but each implementation may have its own set of additional columns.

Is there a way on execution time to extend the model, defining the additional columns based on, let's say, a definition stored on a `.config` file that would be customized according to the specific database where the `EF` was connecting? How would I then set or retrieve values from those columns added on run time?

Thanks,
Alberto Silva

Comment: You can implement an open schema using a single XML column.

Comment: I would also consider a different approach where the model would never be aware of those user added columns, but would allow me to set a value to each of those columns. Something like:
`myEntity.SetCustomColumnValue("u_1stPurchaseDate", DateTime.Now);`

Comment: [Here](http://romiller.com/2013/02/05/extending-and-customizing-code-first-models-part-1/) is an example implementation for a DbContext with extension points.